# Como soluciono este error al momento de importar una base de datos que esta en .zip de sql server

Tags: sql

No se pudo cargar del paquete el modelo de esquema. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac) ------------------------------ INFORMACIÓN ADICIONAL: Error interno. El servicio de plataforma de base de datos con el tipo Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql160DatabaseSchemaProvider no es válido. Debe asegurarse de que el servicio está cargado o debe proporcionar el nombre de tipo completo de un servicio de plataforma de base de datos válido. (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Por favor haz el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio. Es de particular importancia que uses las etiquetas correctas, este problema no parece tener mucho que ver con SQL y sí con SQL-Server. Cada etiqueta tiene una descripción que explica su uso. Por otro lado, SQL Server, hasta donde sé, no reconoce el formato .zip, y al mismo tiempo el mensaje de error contiene el nombre de un espacio de nombres de .NET, así que diría que faltan más etiquetas y una mejor explicación de lo que estás intentando hacer. Para más información mira [ask].